# Emakefile - custom behaviour undefined

Tags: erlang, makefile, behavior

My `test` project is structured this way:

./Emakefile:

```
{"source/*", [debug_info, {outdir, "binary"}]}.
```

./source/test.erl:

```
-module(test).
-behaviour(test_behaviour).
```

./source/test_behaviour.erl:

```
-module(test_behaviour).
-export([behaviour_info/1]).

behaviour_info(callbacks) -> [];
behaviour_info(_) -> undefined.
```

When I use the command `erl -make` in the project directory (`.`), I get the following output:

```
Recompile: source/test_behaviour
Recompile: source/test
source/test.erl:2: Warning: behaviour test_behaviour undefined
```

Why does `erl` print this warning ? It compiled `test_behaviour.erl` before `test.erl`, so I guess it should be able to find `test_behaviour.beam` in the `binary` folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Behaviors are resolved at the compile time. Hence the Erlang compiler should find the behavior beam file and call the behavior module's `behaviour_info/1` function.

Here test_behaviour.beam is not in the code path of the compiler. You can run by calling

```
erl -pa ebin -make
```

This solved the problem for me. I tried specifying in Emakefile but with no luck. Could not find the documentation also.
Also found that oder of -pa ebin has to be before -make (not sure why though).